# Can I index by embedded field in playORM?

Tags: playorm

I have an entity User mapped in playORM. This entity has an embedded field:

```
@NoSqlEmbedded
private List<String> publisherIds = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I need to write a method `findUsersByPublisher`, which would receive a String `publisherId` as argument and return the associated users.

Is it possible to do that? Or do I need to create another entity Publisher to be able to index the way I want?

In affirmative case, would I put the `@NoSqlIndexed` annotation for this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We intend to support something like that but it is not supported right now.  I am thinking something like select u from Users as u where u.publisherIds contains("value1", "value2")

Right now though there is no support in yet for this.

Dean

Comment: Thanks Dean. Every time I know playOrm better I understand it was a great idea.